# Neo4j Bolt driver connection pooling

Tags: java, neo4j, connection-pooling

In the Neo4j bolt driver jar,there is a Config class. The Config class has got a property maxidleconnections which is being set as 10 . It is mentioned that this value corresponds to the maximum number of connections per database URL . Is there any particular reason for this value being set as 10, or how can we increase this connection pool size? Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

To configure this settings, you should use the `ConfigBuilder` like this :

```
Config.ConfigBuilder builder = build();
builder.withMaxIdleSessions(20);
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"), builder.toConfig());
```